# I don't know what's wrong in here and I tried almost everything , But it still doesn't want to work

Tags: python-3.x

```
import time
#Initializing Variables
currentMoney = 0
depositedMoney = 0
takenMoney = 0
#Main Fucntion which shows when the program starts
def Main():
    while True:
        userChoice = input("Welcome to the ATM Organizer. To Preceed Enter 1 To Close Enter 0")
        if userChoice == 1:
            Atm()
        elif userChoice == 0:
            print("Thank you.Good Bye!")
            break
def Atm():
    Handling Invalid Inputs
    while True:
        try:
            atm = int(input("Welcome Inside The ATM , To See your money , Type '1' , To put money to the cash machine , Type '2' , To take money out of the ATM , Type '3' , To Exit the ATM , Type '0' ."))
        except ValueError:
            print("You didn't choose what was given!")
            continue
    Input Choices
        if (atm == 0):
            Main()
        elif (atm == 1):
            print("You Have ",currentMoney," Inside your account.")
            break
        elif (atm == 2):
            money = int(input("How Much money do you want to deposit? "))
            depositedMoney+=money
            currentMoney=depositedMoney
            print("You Have ",currentMoney," Inside Your Account")
            break
        elif (atm == 3):
            while True:
                takeMoney = int(input("How much money do you want to take? "))
                if (takeMoney > currentMoney):
                    print("You don't have that value.")
                    continue
                else:
                    print("LOADING...")
                    time.sleep(3)
                    takenMoney+=takeMoney
                    print("You've taken ",takenMoney," , You now have "(currentMoney-takenMoney," In your account")
                    break
Main()
```

Whenever I try to run it , it highlights that above "break" , when I delete it ,    another error pops up which is the "Main()" at the last code , "and" it keeps doing this ...

I hope I can find an answer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I got your code working. By the looks of things you're new to programming. Your main problem was that you cannot access variables from inside a function if you don't include them as arguments. I recommend you take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm).

The working code:

```
import time
#Initializing Variables
currentMoney = 0
depositedMoney = 0
takenMoney = 0
#Main Fucntion which shows when the program starts
def Main(currentMoney, depositedMoney, takenMoney): # arguments were missing
    while True:
        try:
            userChoice = int(input("Welcome to the ATM Organizer. To Preceed Enter 1 To Close Enter 0")) # "int()" was missing. had to add try and except as well
        except ValueError:
            print("You didn't choose what was given!")
            continue
        if userChoice == 1:
            currentMoney, depositedMoney, takenMoney = Atm(currentMoney, depositedMoney, takenMoney) # was missing
        elif userChoice == 0:
            print("Thank you.Good Bye!")
            break
def Atm(currentMoney, depositedMoney, takenMoney): # arguments were missing
    #Handling Invalid Inputs # comment sign was missing
    while True:
        try:
            atm = int(input("Welcome Inside The ATM , To See your money , Type '1' , To put money to the cash machine , Type '2' , To take money out of the ATM , Type '3' , To Exit the ATM , Type '0' ."))
        except ValueError:
            print("You didn't choose what was given!")
            continue
    #Input Choices # comment sign was missing
        if (atm == 0):
            return currentMoney, depositedMoney, takenMoney # was missing
        elif (atm == 1):
            print("You Have ",currentMoney," Inside your account.")
            return currentMoney, depositedMoney, takenMoney # was missing
        elif (atm == 2):
            money = int(input("How Much money do you want to deposit? "))
            depositedMoney+=money
            currentMoney=depositedMoney
            print("You Have ",currentMoney," Inside Your Account")
            return currentMoney, depositedMoney, takenMoney # was missing
        elif (atm == 3):
            while True:
                takeMoney = int(input("How much money do you want to take? "))
                if (takeMoney > currentMoney):
                    print("You don't have that value.")
                    continue
                else:
                    print("LOADING...")
                    time.sleep(3)
                    takenMoney+=takeMoney
                    print("You've taken ",takenMoney," , You now have ",(currentMoney-takenMoney)," In your account")   # ")" was missing, "," was missing
                    return currentMoney, depositedMoney, takenMoney # was missing
Main(currentMoney, depositedMoney, takenMoney) # arguments were missing
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much , but do I have to return them every time? I could have assigned them to a variable and then use it with the return statement..
and yes I'm new to programming , I have been learning for like 3 or 4 months I don't know , but the problem is I learn a lot of things , designing , and other languages too , JavaScript , PHP , Java and Python , So I'm not that professional , again : thank you so much for your help , I like the program actually...